# CSS: One class VS selecting many elements

Tags: css, responsive-design, grouping

For a responsive website is there a best practice to hide/show elements altogether in a media selector?  E.g. is it better to have a class called .hide_on_desktop (which sets display: none;) and then to add that class to several elements in the website using HTML.

Or to do the following:

```
.element1, .element2, #element3{
    display: none;
}
```

In the above case element1, element2 and element3 are selectors (classes and ids) that already exist.

Which approach is best for a big website?

Comment: you can create helper classes for display:none and for everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a hidden class if you plan to hide several objects. Bootstrap handles this by having classes: .hidden-xs, .hidden-sm, .hidden-md,etc.. in order to hide elements based on device width.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: Thank I will accept this as the correct answer because it will make the CSS files less cluttered and because it will make it easier to add new elements with that class.